# ASP.NET MVC5 DataAnnotations : Compare Attribute is working but ignoring my ErrorMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET MVC5 application and I'm using DataAnnotations for validation.

As a common situation, I have an account creation form with 2 password fields. Here is my model :

```
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "toto", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordConfirmationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.models.LoginModelResources))]
    public String PasswordValidation { get; set; }
```

When I render the page and put 2 different passwords, it's not using "toto" nor my resource text but it displays the default message : 'PasswordValidation' and 'Password' do not match.

Does someone have an idea on why it's ignored ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does your view look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug Fixed in commit 5003c3a8eff3.  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401